# Updating Excel Application.StatusBar within Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

### My current situation:

I am developing a culmination of VBA programs embedded in an excel file (named "Dashboard.xlsm" and an access file "Dashboard.accdb"). These two files talk to one another via VBA in order to help me do some heavy lifting on data that I need to analyze for my company. Because these programs are being distributed to several managers who panic when something doesn't complete within 3 seconds, I need a good way to indicate the progress of the SQL queries that are being run in Access through Excel (because Access is running invisibly in the background).

### My current Excel code:

```vb
Sub generateFRMPComprehensive_ButtonClick(Optional sheetName As Variant)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim directoryPath As String
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL, strInput As String
Dim sArray As Variant
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim directoryName

oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

directoryName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
directoryPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Dashboard Exports"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If IsMissing(sheetName) Then
    sheetName = Application.InputBox("Sheet Name?", "Sheet Selection")
    If sheetName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    If FileFolderExists(directoryPath) = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Creating Export Folder"
        MkDir directoryPath
    End If
End If
'-- Set the workbook path and name
reportWorkbookName = "Report for " & sheetName & ".xlsx"
reportWorkbookPath = directoryPath & "\" & reportWorkbookName
'-- end set


'-- Check for a report already existing
If FileExists(reportWorkbookPath) = True Then
    Beep
    alertBox = MsgBox(reportWorkbookName & " already exists in " & directoryPath & ". Do you want to replace it?", vbYesNo, "File Exists")
    If alertBox = vbYes Then
        Kill reportWorkbookPath
        '-- Run the sub again with the new sheetName, exit on completion.
        generateFRMPComprehensive_ButtonClick (sheetName)
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf alertBox = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf alertBox = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
'-- End check

'- Generate the report

'-- Create new access object
Set appAccess = New Access.Application
'-- End Create

'-- Open the acces project
Application.StatusBar = "Updating Access DB"
Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(directoryName & "\Dashboard.accdb")
appAccess.Visible = False
'-- End open

'-- Import New FRMP Data
Application.StatusBar = "Running SQL Queries"
appAccess.Application.Run "CleanFRMPDB", sheetName, directoryName & "\Dashboard.xlsm"
'-- End Import

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Report for " & sheetName
ActiveWorkbook.Close
appAccess.Application.Run "generateFRMPReport_Access", reportWorkbookPath
Workbooks.Open (reportWorkbookPath)
End Sub
```

### My current Access Code:

```vb
Public Sub generateFRMPReport_Access(excelReportFileLocation As String)
Dim queriesList As Variant

queriesList = Array("selectAppsWithNoHolds", _
    "selectAppsWithPartialHolds", _
    "selectAppsCompleted", _
    "selectAppsCompletedEPHIY", _
    "selectAppsByDivision", _
    "selectAppsByGroup", _
    "selectAppsEPHIY", _
    "selectAppsEPHIN", _
    "selectAppsEPHIYN", _
    "selectApps")


For i = 0 To 9
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , queriesList(i), _
        excelReportFileLocation, True
Next i
End Sub
```

### My Request:

Is there a way that I can call the Application.DisplayStatusBar from within the 'for' loop within Access and pass the name of the query being run?

Alternatively, what other ways could I display this information?

Thank you!!

Comment: Try passing the Excel `Application` to the function in Access (you may need to type it as `Variant` for this to work, since Access won't know the interop type of Excel) and then access `Application.StatusBar` from within there. Disclaimer: I have no idea if this can even work in theory.

Comment: Why are you opening an Access object and calling a defined function? Simply have Excel connect to the database with ADO and import queries into workbook. While Access is both a GUI program and a database, you save the overhead of an external process, namely MSAccess.exe. Plus with ADO users don't need this software installed and should you upsize database, code does not change much (only connection string).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for achieving this, but the two most obvious are to:

1. Execute the queries *from* Excel, and update the status bar *from* Excel
2. Execute the queries *from* Access, but pass the Excel Application reference to Access, so that Access can call back to the Excel status bar.

As your'e driving the activity from Excel, and you *already* have a reference to the Access Application, the first option is the most logical. The second approach is possible - you just need to pass the Excel object to Access, but then you'd be using Excel to automate Access to automate Excel.

You'll need to move the `generateFRMPReport_Access` procedure from the Access VBA into the Excel VBA, and modify your call to the procedure in `generateFRMPComprehensive_ButtonClick`

```vb
Sub generateFRMPComprehensive_ButtonClick(Optional sheetName As Variant)
'...
'appAccess.Application.Run "generateFRMPReport_Access", reportWorkbookPath
generateFRMPReport_Access reportWorkbookPath, appAccess
'...
End Sub

Public Sub generateFRMPReport_Access(excelReportFileLocation As String, appAccess As Access.Application)

  Dim queriesList As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  queriesList = Array("selectAppsWithNoHolds", _
      "selectAppsWithPartialHolds", _
      "selectAppsCompleted", _
      "selectAppsCompletedEPHIY", _
      "selectAppsByDivision", _
      "selectAppsByGroup", _
      "selectAppsEPHIY", _
      "selectAppsEPHIN", _
      "selectAppsEPHIYN", _
      "selectApps")


  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  For i = 0 To 9
      Application.StatusBar = "Running query " & (i + 1) & " of 9"
      appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , queriesList(i), _
          excelReportFileLocation, True
  Next i
  Application.StatusBar = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
End Sub
```