# VBA Excel Application.statusbar - how can one update statusbar of one workbook from another?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, statusbar

In initial workbook **1** I set `application.statusbar="Running..."`.

Then code later opens another excel workbook (lets call this one **2**), using eg `application.run "'Workbook2.xls'!MyMacro"`

I would like to know if it's possible to then update the `statusbar` of initial workbook **1** via the vba code in the second workbook **2** ?

My current understanding is that `application` refers to the current workbook not to another one.

Version of Excel being used: Office 365 Pro Plus x86

***Update to question:***
From comments thus far, my understanding is that if the workbooks are open in the same instance, then `application.statusbar` updates the statusbar in both workbooks. What I am now seeking is how to update the statusbar from once instance of Excel to another with examples of code.

Sites read thus far:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.StatusBar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application%28object%29

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183819/managing-excel-application-state-w-multiple-subroutines

[Updating Excel Application.StatusBar within Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312719/updating-excel-application-statusbar-within-access-vba)

[StatusBar and ScreenUpdate in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076343/statusbar-and-screenupdate-in-excel-2013)

[Application.Statusbar not working as expected in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278177/application-statusbar-not-working-as-expected-in-excel-2013)

Comment: You can update anything if you have a reference variable.

Comment: `application refers to the current workbook` - no, `Application` refers to the entire instance of Excel. The two workbooks in question can be hosted in the same Excel instance, or they can be hosted in different instances, depending on exactly how you open them (with newer Office versions that don't have the MDI interface anymore it's difficult to tell the difference, but it is still there). If they are in different instances, you need to pass the `Application` reference from one to another somehow. It is much easier if you just have them under the same instance.

Comment: ok, lets say they are under the same instance - how can the second opened workbook update the statusbar of the first one?

Comment: @unseen_rider They are the same `statusbar` update one and it'll be present for both

Comment: Ok, and how about different instances?